# How to support WebGL with Chrome in webView android

Tags: android, android-webview, webgl, webchromeclient

I want show a 3D Model in WebView from a link, but in webView it has not support for WebGl. I tried:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

but its not working.

Comment: What Android version are you trying this on?

Comment: @Paul-Jan android Api 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found best solution.
best solution is custom chrome tab.I love it because:  
        1.very fast

        2.support webGl.

        3.Toolbar color

        4.Enter and exit animations

        5.Add custom actions to the Chrome toolbar, overflow menu and bottom toolbar

For more information this [link](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs)  is useful.